# How to connect socket.io and rethinkdb?

Tags: sockets, websocket, socket.io, rethinkdb

After hours of trying. I haven't make it work.

Here's what I have.

```
var app     = require('express')(),
    http    = require('http').Server(app),
    io      = require('socket.io')(http),
    r       = require('rethinkdb');

http.listen(5000);
console.log('Server started on port 5000');

r.connect({db: 'testRealtime'}).then(function(c) {
    r.table('messages').insert(
        { message: "realtime" }
    )

    r.table('messages').changes().run(c)
        .then(function(cursor) {
            cursor.each(function(err, item) {
                io.emit('messages', item)
            })
        })
})
```

As you can see on the above example. I am trying to insert a message realtime and look at it on rethinkdb dashboard. But this doesn't work. I don't know why.

Rethinkdb query `r.db('testRealtime').table('messages').changes()`

Since i'm using angular2. Here's the Service I created

```
import * as io from 'socket.io-client'

export class ChatService {
    private url = 'http://localhost:5000'
    private socket;

    getMessages() {
        this.socket = io(this.url);

        this.socket.on('messages', function(data){
            console.log(data.new_val.query_engine)
        })
    }
}
```

On my component, I just call the getMessages form service. Nothing to worry about angular code. I think it is more about the connection of socket.io and rethinkdb.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You have to do `.run(c)` on your insert query too. And be sure that you run your insert query after you already listen for changes otherwise you are not gonna receive updates. I don't see anything else wrong at first glance.

Comment: Yes. I already figured it out. Thanks tho.